# Extract substrings from a string and output some lines

Tags: ruby

I have this string:

```
a = "hello glass car [clock][flower] candy [apple]"
```

How can I make an array of the words in brackets like `[word]`, and output as follows for each item within?

```
array = ['clock', 'flower', 'apple']    
array.each do |a|
   puts a + 'have'
end
# >> clock have
# >> flower have
# >> apple have
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@spickermann uses a *positive lookbehind* and *positive lookahead* and makes `.*` non-greedy by adding the question mark. That's my preference, but I'll mention the other normal way of doing that, which is using a capture group, and then a way that does not produce an intermediate array.

```
string = "hello glass car [clock][flower] candy [apple]"
```

As

```
string.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/)
  #=> [["clock"], ["flower"], ["apple"]]
```

we would write

```
string.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/).flatten.each { |word| puts "#{word} have" }
clock have
flower have
apple have
```

or

```
string.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/).each { |(word)| puts "#{word} have" }
clock have
flower have
apple have
```

Note that if the `non-greedy` qualifier were removed from the regex we would obtain the following:

```
arr = string.scan(/\[(.*)\]/)
  #=> [["clock][flower] candy [apple"]]
```

that is, an array containing a single element, which is an array containing a single element, the string

```
"clock][flower] candy [apple"
```

See [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-scan), particularly the reference to (capture) groups.

If, as suggested by the question, you simply want to print the results and don't need the array `["clock", "flower", "apple"]`, you could just write the following:

```
string.gsub(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/) { |word| puts "#{word} have" }
clock have
flower have
apple have
  #=> "hello glass car [][] candy []"
```

or

```
string.gsub(/\[(.*?)\]/) { puts "#{$1} have" }
clock have
flower have
apple have
  #=> "hello glass car  candy "
```

discarding the return value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your explanation :)

Comment: Your use of decompositional parentheses with one element as in `|(word)|` was new to me. I can immediately understand what is does, but have never come up with such use. So, it could be used as an (superior) alternative to `*`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regex that matches everything surrounded by square brackets:

```
string = "hello glass car [clock][flower] candy [apple]"
string.scan(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/).each { |word| puts "#{word} have" }
```

Comment: You don't need `each`. Put the block directly after `scan`.